# Retrieve taxonomy terms from ContentItem in Orchard

Tags: c#, orchardcms-1.7

I'trying to retrieve the full list of taxonomy terms from a ContentItem doing something like this:

```
var product = Services.ContentManager.Get<ContentItem>(33);

foreach (var term in product.TermsPart.Terms.Where(x => x.Field == "MyIndex"))
{
    ...
}
```

Can someone help me?

I read it is possible, using dynamic to do this:

```
dynamic product = Services.ContentManager.Get<ContentItem>(33);

foreach (var term in product.MyIndex.Terms)
{
    ...
}
```

but I cannot find the right syntax!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do it is using the ITaxonomyService (http://orchardtaxonomies.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Services/ITaxonomyService.cs)

Inject it on the constructor of your class(controller, dependency or whatever):

```
  //Note that I didn't try this code
    public SomeController(ITaxonomyService taxonomyService){
         var product = Services.ContentManager.Get<ContentItem>(33);
         var terms = taxonomyService.GetTermsForContentItem(product.Id); //Or just 33

   }
```